# Почему парсится все время одна страница?

Tags: python, парсер

Почему парсится все время первая страница, переход по страницам идет нормально, окончание добавляется, но записываются одни и те же данные.

```
def get_html(url, params=None):
    req = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return req

def parse():

    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        pages_count = get_pages_count(html.text)
        products = []
        for page in range(1, pages_count+1):
            print(f'Парсинг страницы {page} из {pages_count}...')
            html = get_html(URL, params=f'strana-{page}')
            products.extend(get_content(html.text))
            print(products)
        save_file(products, FILE)
    else:
        print('Error')
```

Comment: Что такое get_html?

Comment: это ф-ция, которая берет страницу для парсинга def get_html(url, params=None):
    req = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return req

Comment: А вы уверены, что добавление параметра `strana-{page}` является правильным для получения другой страницы?

Comment: да, проблема в этом, появляется вопрос перед strana,  а его не должно быть. как его убрать тогда? 'https://www.petcenter.cz/ptaci/?strana-1'

Comment: Значит меняйте URL напрямую как вам требуется и не используйте params

Comment: решил так def get_html(url):
    res = requests.get(f'{url}', headers=HEADERS)
    return res а при вызове  html = get_html(f'{URL}strana-{page}') Теперь все гуд работает. СПАСИБО!